# python - How much space does a subclass require in memory

Tags: python, class, object, memory, space

Let's say I create some class named A() with two custom methods in it.
When I instantiate it, an object will be created in some address in the memory representinf this instance.
Now I create a subclass of A, for example, B(A) and define one more custom method in it.
My question is, when I instantiate B, the object created in memory will also "contain" the data of the class A, namely the two custom methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance merely references it's class. No extra memory is required to hold those two methods beyond the class definition.

From a memory perspective, the class definition itself is little more that a tuple of refences to the base classes, a reference to it's metatype (`type()` by default) and a dictionary for the attributes (which includes all the methods).

Instances are just a reference to the class, plus either a dictionary of attributes or a fixed set of attributes when using `__slots__` (the latter is more memory efficient but disallows arbitrary extra attributes to be set).